# Swift 3: prepare(for:sender:)

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have a simple entity:

```
extension Team {

@nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Team> {
    return NSFetchRequest<Team>(entityName: "Team")
}

@NSManaged public var name: String?
@NSManaged public var phone: String?
@NSManaged public var department: String?
@NSManaged public var position: String?

}
```

Picture for easy understanding:

[image]

I load current entity from Core Data to App successfully. Furthermore, I have a UITableViewController with property **members** (it's storage of fetch result from Team entity).

> var members: [Team] = []

After app launching (**viewDidLoad(_:)**) **members.count** is equal to 7 and that is right. Also, all these elements of members are using by UITableVIew in UITableViewController.

My task is open Detailed View Controller who will retrieve data from tapped cell. For this delegation I use classic **prepare(for:sender:)** method in UITableViewController (*who is segue.source in current case*):

```
// MARK: - Navigation

extension TeamListViewController {

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    guard segue.identifier == segueIdentifier,
        let memberDetailsViewController = segue.destination as? MemberDetailsViewController else {
        fatalError("Wrong destination!")
    }

    guard let selectedIndex = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row else {
        fatalError("Out of range")
    }

    guard let name       = members[selectedIndex].name,
          let phone      = members[selectedIndex].phone,
          let department = members[selectedIndex].department,
          let position   = members[selectedIndex].position else {

        fatalError("No correct data")
    }

    memberDetailsViewController.memberNameLabel.text!        = name
    memberDetailsViewController.memberPhoneNumberLabel.text! = phone
    memberDetailsViewController.memberDepartmentLabel.text!  = department
    memberDetailsViewController.memberPositionLabel.text!    = position

}

}
```

So, App launches, I tap any cell whichever I want to open for more details and.. App crashes!

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

[image]

However, my variables (*name, phone, department, position*) are ok. They are with values!

Oh, yes. I try to retrieve a data for UILabels in **MemberDetailsViewController** below:

```
// MARK: - IBOutlets
@IBOutlet weak var memberNameLabel:        UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var memberPhoneNumberLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var memberDepartmentLabel:  UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var memberPositionLabel:    UILabel!
```

What is that can be a problem here?

Comment: Instead of setting IBoutles values directly from prepare method(which is not loaded yet), try setting value in viewDidLoad of MemberDetailsViewController(for that you can create stored properties and set value from prepare method).

Comment: Thank you @Sahil. It's a good idea really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of your are set your data in `prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)` method in `TeamListViewController` where `MemberDetailsViewController` is not loaded properly thats way you got `nil`.

My suggestion is: Add Object  like `var members: Team?` in `MemberDetailsViewController` and pass it from  `TeamListViewController` so error will not appear.

Comment: Simple magic! It helped me!

Comment: Glad to help you